# Change background color of JSF form

Tags: html, css, jsf

I have a JSF page with a form on it. I can modify nearly every property of this form but not the background color. So far I've tried it from css like this:

```
.login_panel {
    background-image: none;
    background: gainsboro !important;
    background-color: gainsboro !important;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

And applied this style class to the form like

```
<h:form styleClass="login_panel">...
```

Well every settings is fine, but the background is still white. Is there any way to change the bgcolor of a form? I couldn't find any answer for this so far.

@Edit: Generated HTML source:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Jenny/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Jenny/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.0" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/Jenny/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.0"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Jenny/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=3.0"></script>
        <title>WebMethods Testing Suite</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design/style.css" /></head><body style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
        <center>
            <h1>Jenny</h1>

            <!-- Login to the integration server -->
<form id="j_idt8" name="j_idt8" method="post" action="/Jenny/faces/index.xhtml" class="login_form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt8" value="j_idt8" />
<div id="j_idt8:server_data" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all login_panel"><div id="j_idt8:server_data_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content"><table>
<thead>
<tr><th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">
                            Servers
                        </th></tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr><td colspan="2"><button id="j_idt8:j_idt16" name="j_idt8:j_idt16" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'j_idt8',source:'j_idt8:j_idt16',process:'@all',update:'j_idt8:status'});return false;" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text">Connect</span></button><script id="j_idt8:j_idt16_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('CommandButton','widget_j_idt8_j_idt16',{id:'j_idt8:j_idt16'});</script>
                            <br /><label id="j_idt8:status">
Not initialized...</label></td></tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><label for="j_idt8:url" class="output_label">
Server address</label></td>
<td><table id="j_idt8:url">
    <tr>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="j_idt8:url" id="j_idt8:url:0" value="10.125.112.20:10601" /><label for="j_idt8:url:0"> 10.125.112.20:10601</label></td>
    </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="j_idt8:userName" class="output_label">
User name:</label></td>
<td><input id="j_idt8:userName" name="j_idt8:userName" type="text" value="" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /><script id="j_idt8:userName_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_j_idt8_userName',{id:'j_idt8:userName'});</script></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="j_idt8:password" class="output_label">
Password</label></td>
<td><input id="j_idt8:password" type="password" name="j_idt8:password" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="j_idt8:packageName" class="output_label">
Default package</label></td>
<td><input id="j_idt8:packageName" type="text" name="j_idt8:packageName" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div></div><script id="j_idt8:server_data_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('Panel','widget_j_idt8_server_data',{id:'j_idt8:server_data'});</script><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-494924954700381044:6977213687741547564" autocomplete="off" />
</form>

        </center></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note. This has nothing to do with JSF or Primefaces. It's just a CSS/HTML issue. So you should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Kinda silly of me to notice, but are you sure you apply your styles to the correct selector? )) In your question you ask about styling a `form` element that has a class of `login_form` - and then - you give your css part where the selector is `login_panel` ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can advise to check that the inner `div` that you have in your `form` element is in the normal flow.

Have a look at two fiddles: the first one was stolen from the previous answer and modified a bit, I hope Aquillo doesn't mind =).

http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/m6k3b/3/ - here we may see that the background color is not applied to the form (same situation you have I presume). Pay attention that the `div` is floated - it means that it is removed from the normal flow.

http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/m6k3b/2/ - here I added a simple fix (you may chose other if you know them) for the parent element to so-to-say *see* it's children and prevent it from collapsing.

You can read about the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow) here.

Hope that helps you.